# How can I pull data from a SQL Database that spans an academic year?

Tags: sql, datetime

Basically, I want to pull data from August to May for a given set of dates. Using the between operator works as long as I do not cross the year marker (i.e. BETWEEN 8 AND 12 works -- BETWEEN 8 AND 5 does not). Is there any way to pull this data? Here is the SQL Query I wrote:

```
SELECT count(*), MONTH(DateTime)
FROM Downloads
WHERE YEAR(DateTime) BETWEEN 2009 AND 2010 AND MONTH(DateTime) BETWEEN 8 AND 5 
GROUP BY MONTH(DateTime)
ORDER BY MONTH(DateTime)"
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Eric R.

Comment: Splitting it up like that would be incorrect.  You are basically saying `(year >= 2009 && year <= 2010) && (month >= 8 && month <= 5)`.  The last part would never match.  You could flip them to get unexpected results, or change it to OR `(month >= 8 || month <= 5)` which matches 1/1/2009-4/28/2009, 8/1/2009-4/28/2010, 8/1/2010 - 12/31/2010, also incorrect.  You really need to keep the month and year together: `date1 >= '8/1/2009' && date2 < '6/1/2010'`

Comment: Logically, what you want is WHERE (YEAR(DateTime) = 2009 AND MONTH(DateTime) >= 8) OR (YEAR(DateTime) = 2010 AND MONTH(DateTime) <= 5) or WHERE CONCAT(YEAR(DateTime),MONTH(DateTime)) BETWEEN 200908 AND 201005 (catsing to numeric as necessary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using BETWEEN with YEAR() and MONTH() is going to ruin any chance of using indexes on that column anyway. I would use:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [count],
    YEAR(my_date) AS [year],
    MONTH(my_date) AS [month]
FROM
    Downloads
WHERE
    my_date >= '2009-08-01' AND
    my_date < '2010-06-01'
GROUP BY
    YEAR(my_date),
    MONTH(my_date)
ORDER BY
    YEAR(my_date), MONTH(my_date)
```

(I used my_date because I can't bring myself to refer to a column as DateTime) :)

Comment: Thanks Tom. I didn't create this database and I absolutely hate that it has a column called DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT count(*), MONTH(DateTime)
FROM Downloads
WHERE DateTime>'2009/8/1 00:00:00' AND datetime<'2010/6/1 00:00:00'
GROUP BY MONTH(DateTime)
ORDER BY MONTH(DateTime)
```

Comment: You're going to want to use >= 2009/8/1